# Create array with values that match from database

Tags: php

Is there a way to create a group where a row match? Hard to explain but ill try.

If I have a database with these fields:

```
ID:  Name:      GROUP_ID:
1    Jacob      1
2    Jonathan   1
3    Jesper     2
4    Jeod       2
5    Jeod       3
```

and I have a function that retrieves all of this data using `PDOStatement::fetchAll`

```
$users = $page->retrieve_users();
```

and then I want each `GROUP_ID` to be in a grouped div.

Now this displays all the names

```
foreach($users as $user){

echo "<div>".$user["name"]."</div>";

}
```

How do I configure it so each `user["name"]` that has the same `GROUP_ID` is in a own div?

I know I have to create a new array for each different `GROUP_ID` but I dont even know how to do that since I want it to be flexible meaning if I add a new user with a unique `GROUP_ID` it will be sorted to its own.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep track of the current `GROUP_ID` and close / open your `div` when it changes. Assuming that the results are ordered by `GROUP_ID`...

Comment: Can you post the code for retrieve_users(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Categorize your users by group_id
2. Loop over each group's users to display them

Example code

```
$groups = array();

foreach($users as $user){
  $group = $user["GROUP_ID"];
  if(!array_key_exists($group,$groups)){
    $groups[$group] = array();
  }
  $groups[$group][] = $user["name"];
}

foreach($groups as $group => $members){
  echo "This is group $group\n";
  foreach($members as $username){
    echo $username."\n"; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$usersByGroup = array();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $usersByGroup[$user['group_id']][] = $user['user'];
}
```

This array looks like :

```
array(
    1 => array("Jacob", "Jonathan" ),
    2 => array("Jesper", "Jeod" ),
    3 => array("Jeod")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_name_array = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
  $user_name_array[$user['GROUP_ID']][] = $user['Name'];
 }

foreach ($user_name_array as $group_id => $user_names) {
  foreach ($user_names as $user_name) {
    echo "<div>$user_name</div>\n";
  }
}
```